# XSL - add a value to attribute if value doesn't exist

Tags: xml, xslt

When the element is created I need to change add value to **data-id** attribute (which is working), but once this value is set, I need to preserve it. The problem is that, if anything order is changed during creating the form, the id will be changed, and for **data-id** I need a fixed value. Any ideas.

I have this code for creating input element:

```
<div class="field" align="left">
    <xsl:element name="input">
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$field_id" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$field_id" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="maxlength"><xsl:value-of select="@maxlength" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="minlength"><xsl:value-of select="@minlength" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">text</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="data-id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$field_id" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="required">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@required='required'">required</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="onchange">
                                            fieldPropertyChange('smalltext', '<xsl:value-of select="$field_id" />');
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the opposite of `reqired="required"` is not `required="false"`. Read the [spec on boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute).

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Just leave out the "required" attribute if a field is optional.

Additionally you are missing [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates). `<xsl:attribute>` is not often needed in general and not at all in your sample. The same goes for `<xsl:element>`.

Here is what your code should look like.

```
<div class="field" align="left">
    <input
        id="{$field_id}" name="{$field_id}" type="text" class="text" 
        value="{.}" data-id="{$field_id}"
        onchange="fieldPropertyChange('smalltext', '{$field_id}')"
    >
        <xsl:copy-of select="@maxlength|@minlength|@required[. = 'required']" />
    </input>
</div>
```

You want an `<input>` with a bunch of attributes. And you want to copy the attributes `@maxlength`, `@minlength` (if they exist in the source) and `@required` (but only if it actually has a value of `'required'` in the source).

`<xsl:copy-of>` is the right choice for such a situation.

On a further note, you might want to get rid of `onchange`. I recommend you use jQuery and a separate script file for event handling and keep all Javascript out of your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful info :). I didn't make the xls code, kinda inherit it, and at the moment we can't change that, so I have this almost 4k lines of pure chaos.

Comment: Have fun cleaning up the mess. :) BTW, you can write XSL templates to re-write your XSL templates. Just as an idea. If your input XSL is kind of repetitive, that would be one way of cleaning it up.